# In C# what does this syntax do and what is it called?

Tags: c#, syntax

I'm guessing this is saying the Constructor for OrderRepository passes its parameter to the base constructor?

`public OrderRepository(MFEntitiesContainer context) : base(context) { }`

Comment: Is this a feature of all versions of C#?

Comment: It is. See the documentation for VS 2003: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87(v=VS.71).aspx

Comment: You can also use "this" instead of "base" to chain a call to a different constructor *in the current type* rather than *in the base type*.

Comment: Chaining .ctors within the same type can be _very_ convenient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called **constructor chaining** - you are chaining the constructor to the base constructor overload.

As you assume, it passes the parameter to the matching base class constructor.

Comment: Thanks.  Exactly what I needed. I was looking for the terminology to describe the syntax, so I could google it myself.

Answer (score 5):

Correct. Its calling the "base constructor".

See this page on constructors.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115(v=VS.100).aspx